# Как скомпилировать c++ файл?(ubuntu)

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu

Подскажите как скомпилировать файл. Использую g++ пытаюсь скомпилить

```
adel@comp:~/Документы/c++$ g++ -lm -o output firs.cpp
adel@comp:~/Документы/c++$
```

создается файл [image: выходит ошибка]

вот сам cpp файл

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
       cout<<"Hello world";
       return 0; //Возвращаем 0 - код возврата для ОС
}
```

Comment: в терминале ./output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запуск двойным нажатием определяет настройка Вашего проводника. Есть вероятность, что она запускается в новой сессии терминала, которая Вам не отображается, а Вы думайте что запуск не произошел...

Для запуска данного приложения Вам необходимо начать сессию командной оболочки bash(ну или чего-то еще что у Вас есть zsh, sh) которая будетВам доступна, перейти в дир. с Вашим кодом и вызвать gcc(g++) (ну или LLVM clang) для сборки Вашего кода

```
g++ ./source.cpp
```

Ну или смотря что вы хотите от gcc)) Используйте Ваш рецепт из вопроса ))
После этого Вы найдете a.out ELF файл

Для запуска Вы должны быть уверенны что стоит x(execute) бит. можете проверить этой командой

```
ls -l | fgrep a.out
```

И получить на выходе что-то по типу

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 usr usr 9048 dec 18 00:00 a.out
```

Если есть x биты - то все отлично, его нет, то сначала вызовете

```
chmod +x ./app
```

И далее просто запустите его - В линухе по причине безопасности для запуска нужен абсолютный путь - это можно сделать так :

```
./app - в конкретной директории
```

или

```
/path_to_/app  - из любой директории
```

где ./ укажет текущий путь($pwd)

Совет: не собирайте все командами в оболочке... лучше собирать утилитой make по рецептам указанным в Makefile.

Для этого Вам понадобится makefile - который можно или написать, или генерировать (вариантов тьма, но лучше научиться юзать CMake https://cmake.org/ - там все есть) он поможет Вам организовать сборку больших решений))

CMake генерирует Вам makefile в соответствии с конфигами которые Вы ему напишите )

Самый минимум для CMake CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16.0-rc3)

set(PROJECT_NAME "Test_for_stack")
project(${PROJECT_NAME} DESCRIPTION "C++" LANGUAGES C CXX)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})

set(SOURCE_CODE_CPP_MAIN ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/source.cpp)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_CODE_CPP_MAIN })
```

Или напишите makefile сами ) Вот лайтовый пример makefile

```
CC := g++-9
CLEAN_COM := rm -rf
compile_flags := -std=c++17 -m64 -march=native -Wall -O2 -Wpedantic -pedantic -fno-inline -DNDEBUG

app: main.o
$(CC) -o app main.o $(compile_flags)

main.o: main.cpp
    $(CC) -E main.cpp $(compile_flags) >> main.i
    $(CC) -S main.i $(compile_flags) >> main.s
    $(CC) -c main.s $(compile_flags) >> main.o 

.PHONY : clean_buf 
clean_buf :
    $(CLEAN_COM) main.i main.s main.o

.PHONY : clean 
clean :
    $(CLEAN_COM) main.i main.s main.o app
```

Далее просто дерните в дир. где CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake . && make
```

Или

```
cmake . && cmake. — build
```

Comment: хороший у Вас make файл. Прям таки лайтовый.  плюс вызов смейка написан кривовато.  Он не поможет запустить обычный make файл.

Comment: @KoVadim Так лучше???

Comment: @KoVadim И чем вызов cmake по Вашему кривой?

Comment: CMakeLists.txt для такого проекта пишет в две строки, ну ок, в три, что бы 11 плюсы на [старых компиляторах разрешить](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/tutorial/index.html). Во вторых, вызывать явно make для компиляции после cmake  не нужно - cmake --build . сделает все в лучшем виде (он даже корректно под виндой соберет, а make - не факт). В третьих. по хорошему, для помойки от cmake нужно создавать каталог, в котором все собирать. А обычный Makefile ... вот реально нужно препроцессировать файл?

Comment: CMake - это хорошо, но перед тем, как его предлагать, я думаю стоит сначала обяснить ТСу, что проблема не в том, что он не использует CMake, а в том, у него у него не настроен запуск исполняемых файлов из проводника дабл-кликом.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat я указал что все надо сделать из терминала

Comment: @Andrey Я вижу. :) Я имею в виду, что от такого ответа может создаться впечатление, что без CMake работать не будет.

Comment: @KoVadim не пользуюсь WIn32 и cmake . --build просто дергает make

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Я поменяю местами эти 2 пункта

Comment: @Andrey - а можно использовать `cmake -GNinja .` и потом собирать ninja (считается, что на больших проектах оно быстрее). Вот только `--build` сам все запустит, а ручной make - не сможет.

Comment: @KoVadim по поводу "теневой сборки" я думаю это лишнее в рамках данного вопроса, но из 3-х Ваших замечаний по факту реальных проблем 0

Comment: @KoVadim Вы видите в теме вопроса или моем ответе Ninja ?

Comment: я и cmake не видел. и make. Кстати, make умный, он даже по `make first` соберет проект (при условии конечно, что имя исходника `first.cpp`.

Comment: @KoVadim мы с Вами обсуждаем не те проблемы. Если вы настаиваете я выложу 10 файлов конфигурации cmake для сборки hello world. Вот мне лично смешно

Comment: а самой главной информации для OP'а, что он **уже «скомпилировал» файл**  и у него просто **не получается его запустить** в ответе всё равно нет...

Comment: @Fat-Zer - в ответе все есть

Comment: В ответе есть также авторская отсебятина из мира венды, о том, что якобы приложения делятся на консольные и гуевые - не делятся. Линуксовые приложения все одинаково "консольные" в терминах венды.

Comment: @gdg уберем))) спасибо